# Is there still a UI to edit a table in Drupal 10?

Tags: drupal

I'm working on a project in Drupal 10. I used composer to build the project and used the standard installation. When I go to add a table in the content management section, I can select the number of rows and columns, but don't seem to have the ability to edit the table attributes as I think was possible in Drupal 8.
[image]

Is there a package I was supposed to include to allow that kind of editing or is it not part of Drupal 10?

I have been looking in the Drupal docs but can't find anything that seems to cover this topic. There seem to be plenty of articles about how to build a table using just html which I know how to do but I'm confused why I can't access the table attributes like it seems I could in version 8.

Thanks for any assistance!